# Reading Multiple excel File Using Spring Batch Extension

Tags: spring-batch

I am trying to read multiple excel files using Spring-Bath-Excel. In my scenario i don't  know i advance how many files client will process i.e. if data would be very large, excel file will be split into multiple files like **records1.xls** ,**records2.xls**, **records3.xls**..

Is there any kind of MultiResourceItemReader available in Spring-Batch-Excel?  I tried to set multiple resources at run time and also tried to use the patterns **records*.xls** but PoiItemReader did't allow me to do that .

I am using **PoiItemReader** for that .

Comment: Use a MultiResourceItemReader with a *.xls pattern coupled with a PoiItemReader; this is how a MultiResourceItemReader should be used. Net is full of example

Comment: Luca is correct.  You cloud also partition via the `MultiResourcePartitioner` and process the files in parallel if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

To Read Multiple Excel

```
package com.abc.ingestion.job.dci;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
import org.springframework.batch.extensions.excel.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.extensions.excel.streaming.StreamingXlsxItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.extensions.excel.support.rowset.DefaultRowSetFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.extensions.excel.support.rowset.StaticColumnNameExtractor;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig {
  @Autowired
  private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

  @Autowired
  private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

  // Create input folder in resources
  @Value("input/DCI*.xlsx")
  private Resource[] inputResources;

  @Bean
  public MultiResourceItemReader<CouncilMapper> multiResourceItemReader() {
    MultiResourceItemReader<CouncilMapper> resourceItemReader = new MultiResourceItemReader<>();
    resourceItemReader.setResources(inputResources);
    resourceItemReader.setDelegate(reader());
    return resourceItemReader;
  }

  private RowMapper<CouncilMapper> excelRowMapper() {
    return new Mapper();
  }

  @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
  @Bean
  public StreamingXlsxItemReader<CouncilMapper> reader() {

    final String[] COLUMNS = {"Reg_Type","RegUnder","registration_no","registration_date","course","Other_Course","LRegDate","council_name","full_name","CatName","Other_Category","father_name","mother_name","gender","nationality","date_of_birth","place_of_birth","permanent_address","business_address","current_city","current_state","permanent_city","mobile_number","OfficialTelephone","email","aadhar_number","PanNo","IsDeleted","CreatedDate","UpdatedDate","speciality_name"};

    var factory = new DefaultRowSetFactory();
    factory.setColumnNameExtractor(new StaticColumnNameExtractor(COLUMNS));


    StreamingXlsxItemReader<CouncilMapper> reader = new StreamingXlsxItemReader<>();
    reader.setLinesToSkip(1);
    reader.setRowSetFactory(factory);
    reader.setRowMapper(excelRowMapper());
    return reader;
  }

  @Bean
  ItemWriter<CouncilMapper> writer() {
    return new Writer();
  }

  @Bean
  public Job readFilesJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory
            .get("readFilesJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(excelFileStep())
            .build();
  }

  @Bean
  public Step excelFileStep() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("excelFileStep")
            .<CouncilMapper, CouncilMapper>chunk(5)
            .reader(multiResourceItemReader())
            .writer(writer())
            .build();
  }
}
```

Mapper Class

```
package com.abc.ingestion.job.dci;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.extensions.excel.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.batch.extensions.excel.support.rowset.RowSet;

public class Mapper implements RowMapper<CouncilMapper> {

    @Override
    public CouncilMapper mapRow(RowSet rowSet) throws Exception {
        var rowSetMetaData = rowSet.getMetaData();
        String[] columnNames = rowSetMetaData.getColumnNames();
        String[] rowData = rowSet.getCurrentRow();

        var mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Map<String, String> excelData = new HashMap<>();
        IntStream.range(0, columnNames.length).forEach(index -> excelData.put(columnNames[index], rowData[index]));
        return mapper.convertValue(excelData, CouncilMapper.class);
    }


}
```